# Suitescript to return a the vendor prices for a selected item

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Good evening all, and Merry Christmas!!

I feel like I'm bumping my ass at the sky on this...

I know the vendor prices for each item are in a sublist under each item, but I can't for the life of me figure our how to retrieve said information.

I've tried a search but it just refuses to work.

Likewise I've tried looking for a sublist internal id for search "lines" in the item record, but with no luck. i did read somewhere about an 'itemvendor' sublist, but itemRecord.getItemLineCount('itemvendor') is not recognised.

Any thoughts anyone?

Cheers

Steve

Edit: I was able to achieve the desired result with the following code (basically the same as @Mike Robbins code sample):

```
var itemRecord = nlapiLoadRecord('inventoryitem',itemID);
var lines = itemRecord.getLineItemCount('itemvendor');
for (var i=1; i <= lines; i++) {
    var vendor = itemRecord.getLineItemValue ('itemvendor','vendor',i);
    if (vendor == vendorID ) {
        nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue(SUBLIST_Items,'custrecordvpri_currentprice',itemRecord.getLineItemValue('itemvendor','purchaseprice',i))
        nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue(SUBLIST_Items,'custrecordvpri_vendorcurrency',itemRecord.getLineItemValue('itemvendor','vendorcurrencyname',i))
        nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue(SUBLIST_Items,'custrecordvpri_prefer',itemRecord.getLineItemValue('itemvendor','preferredvendor',i))
        i = lines + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this in a search. The field is vendorcost. Note that if you just use "vendor" instead of 'entityid', 'vendor' you'll get the preferred vendor info:

```
nlapiSearchRecord('item', null, [
    new nlobjSearchFilter('vendorcost', null, 'greaterthan', 0),
    new nlobjSearchFilter('itemid', null, 'contains', 'cable')
], [
    new nlobjSearchColumn('itemid'),
    new nlobjSearchColumn('entityid', 'vendor'),
    new nlobjSearchColumn('vendorcost')
]).forEach(function(it) {
    console.log(it.getValue('itemid') + ' ' + it.getValue('entityid', 'vendor') + ' ' + it.getValue('vendorcost'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys, got it sorted now. Turns out 'itemvendor' does work, Eclipse IDE was flagging it as an invalid field name for items.

Thank you both for your answers.

Comment: There are a couple of potential problems with the selected answer. You incur a cost for each nlapiLoadRecord call and if you run this outside of a scheduled script then load record will break your code if the PO has more than 50 lines (or 100 I don't have the numbers in front of me)With the search sample all the item internal IDs could be collected into a filter to get all the prices in a single call. The other issue is that you must know the record type and if you have a mix of inventory and non-inventory items you'll have to do a lookup to use the load record.

Comment: Thanks for the advice BK... I had partially considered the governance cost for the loadRecord call, thankfully in this particular case, it's just a search of a single record.

However your answer does answer the next stage of my project. I'm not using this to populate a PO, but rather a full custom process to automate the review process when a supplier bill price differs to that of the PO, and a chain of process to review a customised client pricing system. I see no reason why I can't call the search from a suitelet to avoid permission problems etc...

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that the `itemvendor` sublist has the vendor purchase price.  This code is working for me:

```js
var item = nlapiLoadRecord('inventoryitem', 122)
var lineItemCount = item.getLineItemCount('itemvendor');
for (var i = 1; i <= lineItemCount; i++) {
    var cost = item.getLineItemValue('itemvendor', 'purchaseprice', i);
    nlapiLogExecution('debug', 'cost', cost);
}
```